# Accessing layout folder at runtime on Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am developing an Android app with several ActionBarActivity, each one displaying a form.
A main ActionBarActivity provides access to the form list.
The contentView for each form has got its own layout XML file.

Now, every time I want to add a new form, I create a new XML file, but I would like the main ActionBarActivity to find automatically all the XML files, produce ActionBarActivity for all of them and the respective intents.

Is this possible?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "load all the forms" a bit more. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I mean that I want an ActionBarActivity for each layout XML file, but I want to avoid writing new code every time I add a new layout

Comment: So how are you going to deal with the values in the forms and doing something with them?  Displaying them that way is easy (have the list activity pass the resource id to display as a parameter to the intent).  Dealing with the output isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a layout resource by its name like this:

```
int layoutId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(layoutName, "layout"), getContext().getPackageName());
```

Comment: This seems to solve the problem of passing the layout id, but introduces the need for the layout name.

Maybe I can store all the layout names in a file.

Comment: In any case the layout name is something you can control whereas layout ids is something the build system creates anew each time

Comment: I've created an array resource with the list of all layout names, and it works!
Thank you!

Comment: On the second thought it is also possible to specify an exact id for a resource by means of defining an "id" resource in ids.xml if I remember correctly.